# MAUI find out if something is on screen does not work as expected

Tags: maui

I have got a MAUI app without a Navbar and with a fixed upper part and a label and some
radiobuttons at the bottom. I want to find out (in code) if all of the label and all of the radiobuttons
do fit onto the screen.
My idea was to find out the position and height of the bottom-most radiobutton and compare this to
the screen size. It does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Reproduction steps:
Take the MAU default app. On MainPage.xaml

- remove the outer ScrollView, but leave the VerticalStackLayout.
- as the bottom-most element of the VerticalStackLayout, add this:

```
<VerticalStackLayout Margin="0,2,0,0">
    <Label x:Name="lbBottom">XXX</Label>
    <Label x:Name="lbMyText"
        Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI bla bla bla Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App 
            Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI bla bla bla Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App 
            Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI bla bla bla Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App "
        SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
        SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
        FontSize="18"
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <RadioButton x:Name ="rb1" Content="Maui?"  />
    <RadioButton x:Name ="rb2" Content="Maui?"  />
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

Add  Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"  to AppShell.xaml. Top-most part of AppShell.xaml then should look like this:

```
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp2.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp2"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">
```

Add this function to MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public Point GetScreenCoords(VisualElement view)
{
    var result = new Point(view.X, view.Y);
    while (view.Parent is VisualElement parent)
    {
        result = result.Offset(parent.X, parent.Y);
        view = parent;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Add this code to the bottom of the OnCounterClicked method:

```
var dens = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density;
lbBottom.Text = Convert.ToInt32(DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height).ToString();
lbBottom.Text += " " + Convert.ToInt32(dens * (GetScreenCoords(rb2).Y + rb2.Height)).ToString();
```

Run the app on "Windows machine". Click the button.
Something like the picture is shown. Screen size is 768 and according to my calculation, the lower edge of the second radiobutton is at 583.
But you even can't see the full label lbMyText and none of the radiobuttons. (It is the same problem when running on Android emulator. Didn't yet test physical device.)
What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to achieve? What's the purpose of what you're trying here? Maybe it can be solved differently, if you provide information about *why* you're trying to figure out if something fits into the viewport.

Comment: I want to make sure that the label and the radiobuttons are visible on screen. And I want to avoid a scrollbar.   Therefore I want to find out if all of the label and all of the radiobuttons are visible / do fit onto the screen. If not, I'd maybe use another font or remove temporarily some of the upper fixed parts of the app.

Comment: Sounds too complicated to me. You could design for certain screen sizes and use different layouts depending on the width or height without actually checking if a control fits into the viewport. You may also want to check out the [OnScreenSize Markup Extension](https://github.com/carolzbnbr/OnScreenSizeMarkup.Maui). Note that this only works with mobile devices. Also, the window size on desktops is not comparable to a physical screen size.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that all controls in the view do not exceed the bounds of the view and without using scroll view, you can use the `Margin` and `Padding` properties of the controls to control the distance between the controls and the distance between the controls and view.

For example, you can use the following code to set the `Stacklayout` to a distance of 50 from the upper, left, lower and right borders. Specifically, you can refer to [Position controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/align-position?view=net-maui-7.0#position-controls).

```
​<StackLayout Padding="50,50,50,50">
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my problem properly. My real problem is,  that I cannot find out if something is visible on screen or not.    Adding a padding or margin won't help me at all.  Please check my example.   Stuff is not visible because it is outside of the screen on the bottom. But my calculation of its position does not work.  Oh well, probably it is a bug in MAUI.